# Recover Storage Folder in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I've deleted the storage folder by mistake, the problem is that I did it with a "rm -rf storage" folder and I cannot recover it.

So, is there a way to "regenerate" the folder and its child folders again?

Thank you!

Comment: It had any data in it? or just empty folder structure?

Comment: @JilsonThomas just empty folder structure.

Comment: Then you can just manually create those. It has three folders: app, framework and logs. The framework folder has three folders in it. cache, sessions, views. Thats all.

Comment: @JilsonThomas thank you! I was wondering if there was a command or something, but it work perfectly! Thank you

Comment: I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just manually create those. It has three folders: app, framework and logs. The framework folder has three folders in it. cache, sessions, views. Thats all.

Comment: can't create storage folder from ftp and cmd